# Arduino: if I use delayMicroseconds() more than once, does the values of the function have to add to 1000?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

As part of a school class we're learning the basics of Arduino, using the Arduino UNO board. The tutorial we're using is part of the 16Hz Guide (http://www.16hertz.com/product/16hertz-ultimate-uno-guide-illustrated-in-progress/) and we were doing tutorial C3.1. I asked my teacher the following, but he couldn't answer. I haven't been able to find an answer in the book or on the net, which is why I'm asking here.

"If using delayMicroseconds() more than once, do the values of the function have to add to 1000?"

The code of the tutorial goes like this:

```
void setup {
pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
}

void loop {
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(200);
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(800);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you want the pattern to repeat (approximately) every millisecond.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful!